# Angular 4: Getting component property values. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm a fairly green Angular 1 dev trying to get my head around Angular 4. So far so good but I'm hung up on what I'm sure is a pretty simple problem that one of you can solve in a second.

In my template I have this tag

```
<app-card [cardsType]="majorArcana"></app-card>
```

Here's the card.component.ts for

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CardsDataService } from '../cards-data.service'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})

export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

    cardData: any;

    @Input() cardsType: string;


    constructor(private CardsDataService: CardsDataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.CardsDataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
            this.cardData = data.tarot;
        });

        console.log(this.cardsType);
    }

}
```

I'm probably just misunderstanding how this works but I would have thought that @Input() cardsType: string; would log this.cardsType as "majorArcana" in the console.

Is that not how it works?

Comment: How it is written here, majorArcana is a property that belongs to the component that has the app-card tag written inside. Here you are saying that your input (cardsType) will have the value of the majorArcana property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are saying that you want to pass in a property of the parent component named `majorArcana`:

```
<app-card [cardsType]="majorArcana"></app-card>
```

You should be able to pass in the string directly like this:

```
<app-card [cardsType]="'majorArcana'"></app-card>
```

**Edit:** check out the answer from @PankajParkar for the other way.

Comment: or like this `cardsType="majorArcana"`

Comment: Ah. Ok. I was operating under the instruction that I had to use either [] or () to bind data from a property. I see that that's definitely the case for expressions but with a string I actually need to put it in single quotes to specify that the value is a string. 

For a string is this the preferred method or is @PankakParkar's version the method? Because both work.

Comment: @BryanWhite Personally, the brackets make it clear to me that the `app-card` component has an `Input` named `cardsType`, whereas without the brackets maybe I could think that attribute is there for another reason. But if you will always be passing in a string literal I think either way is fine.

Comment: @BryanWhite this answer is preferred way of passing data to component, even though you can do it with my suggested way..

Answer (score 3):

Basically what happens is when you wrap your attribute with `[]` it evaluates that expression against component context and whatever evaluated value gets assigned. So here in this case `majorArcana` was evaluated to `undefined`(and you were expected it to be passed as string)

You could overcome this issue by just using `attribute` instead of `property binding`.

```
cardsType="majorArcana"
```

The other & preferred way would be [`@Frank Modica`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191991/2435473)'s answer. As its already covered I'm just linking it to Frank's answer.

Comment: Great to know! Thanks for your help!